# How to move 2D character by holding mouse click or touch in Unity3D. (X axis only)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D and this will be my first project. I am starting simple, but I am getting hung up on something that I know has to be an easy fix. However, with my limited knowledge I have spent all night researching, watching tutorials, and testing different codes, with no success. I know this mostly due to me just not knowing the correct terminology to search, so I apologize in advance.

What I am trying to accomplish:

I am making a mobile game in portrait mode. I will have a static "player" in the middle of the screen. I want to control that character by tapping on the screen and having him move left or right based on where I tapped on the screen. I only want the character to move while the input is held down. (ie: I don't want to tap the left side of the screen briefly, and the character move all the way to that move. I want to have to tap and hold, and as long as I am holding the input, he moves until he is at the touched area.)

But I want to be able to do this with mouse clicks, or with touch input. Much of the code I am finding uses "Input.touchCount > 0" and other "touch" related code. But when using that, my mouse clicks do not register. That being said, I am trying to do this all with "Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)".

This code I currently have is not bad. It moves the player to wherever I click. (and has a nice click target to show where I touch on the screen). But it does not stop moving when I let go of the click, and it also moves on the Y axis. I need this guy to only move left and right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickToMove : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    float speed = 6f;
    Vector2 targetPos;

private void Start(){
    targetPos = transform.position;
}

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            target.position = targetPos;
        }
        if((Vector2)transform.position != targetPos){
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You need to adjust your code like below,

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        targetPos.y = 0; // I fixed Y value to zero you may change this to value you want
        target.position = targetPos;
        if((Vector2)transform.position != targetPos)
        {
             transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tested this, and was having an issue where when I clicked the mouse, the player only moved one slight frame over. It did not continue to move. But I was able to fix it by swapping out GetMouseButtonDown with GetMouseButton. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh right, sorry I am fixing the answer. Happy to help. If it is the correct answer for you you must accept the answer on left for other people.